# Avoid Instagram suspecting if trying to connect with Instaloader Python API, how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, networking, instaloader

I am using the Instaloader Python API for a project. Every time I successfully log-in I get a notification on my Instagram app that someone tried to connect to my account. Everything is ok, I can simply mark the option that was me to connect, but I would like to know if there is a way to directly login from Instaloade avoiding this troublesome situation.

Every time I login I simply do:

```
import instaloader as ig

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    username = "user"
    password = "passwd"
    loader = ig.Instaloader()
    
    loader.login( username, password )
```

Comment: Also overtime it will request you to update the password, and in my case, the last attempts fail to fetch all the profiles.

Comment: @Dane411 exactly